# Build a shell command in a string for later execution portably

Tags: shell

I am trying to do the following command in `bash` and `dash`:

```
x="env PATH=\"$PATH:/dir with space\""
cmd="ls"
"$x" $cmd
```

This fails with

> -bash: env PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/dir
>   with space": No such file or directory

Note the following works:

```
env PATH="$PATH:/dir with space" $cmd
```

The reason I am assigning to variable `x` *env*, is because it is part of a larger command wrapper to `$cmd`, which is also a complicated variable.

It's more complex than the initial example. I have logic in setting these variables,, instead of repeating them each time. Eventually the invocation is as shown here:

```
path_value="$PATH"
invocation="env PATH=\"$path_value\" $other_val1 $other_val2"
base="python python_script.py --opt1=a,b,c script_args"
add_on="$base more_arg1 more_arg2"
"$invocation" $base
```

Comment: Did you try escaping the spaces?

Comment: look at a simpler example: `x="echo hello"; "$x"` - this returns `echo hello: command not found` - try running it without the quotes around "$x".

Comment: Given that you mention a subprocess in a comment below: are you really building the command-line string using _shell_ code? Different considerations apply if you construct the string in Python.

Comment: You may not need `env` at all. `PATH="$PATH:/dir with space" python arg1 arg2`, for instance, runs `python` with a modified `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell array to store and reuse:

```
x=(env PATH="$PATH:/dir with space")
cmd="ls"
"${x[@]}" "$cmd"
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution - use a shell array.

Comment: That's a good solution. I must add a caveat, I am using this in an environment which does not support bash arrays or {}.

Comment: But you tagged it as `bash`. What shell is that?

Comment: It runs as a direct subprocess call on a variety of platforms, using the default shell. Usually bash, but sometimes dash.

Comment: @JonathanAbrahams There is no good, safe way to do this in POSIX shell; that's why so many other shells provide support for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

[anubhava's helpful array-based `bash` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621465/45375) is the best choice if you can assume *only* `bash` (which appeared to be the case initially).

Given that you must also support `dash`, which almost exclusively supports POSIX `sh` features only, arrays are not an option.

*Assuming that you fully control or trust the values that you use to build your command line in a string*, you can use `eval`, which [should generally be avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048):

```
path_value="$PATH"
invocation="env PATH=\"$path_value\" $other_val1 $other_val2"
base="python python_script.py --opt1=a,b,c script_args"
add_on="$base more_arg1 more_arg2"

eval "$invocation $add_on"
```